# When I clicked on submit button after entering info in my html form, it shows the following error. Please fix my code

Tags: mysql-workbench

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near at line 2

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "Root";
$dbname = "yahuas";


$first_name=$_POST["first_name"];
$last_name=$_POST["last_name"];
$relationship=$_POST["relationship"];
$number=$_POST["number"];
$street=$_POST["street"];
$town=$_POST["town"];
$postcode=$_POST["postcode"];
$contact_number=$_POST["contact_number"];


// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO nextofkin (first_name, last_name, relationship, number, street, town, postcode, contact_number)
VALUES ($first_name', '$last_name','$relationship','$number','$street','$town','$postcode','$contact_number')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>



<html>
<body>

<form action="nextofkinform.php" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
Relationship: <input type="text" name="relationship"><br>
House Number: <input type="text" name="number"><br>
Street: <input type="text" name="street"><br>
Town: <input type="text" name="town"><br>
Postcode: <input type="text" name="postcode"><br>
Contact Number: <input type="text" name="contact_number"><br>

<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

> I need help with the syntax please
>   When I clicked on submit button after entering info in my html form,
>   it shows the following error. Please fix my code.

Comment: I notice that you do not have a leading single-quote character around $first_name'. But your real problem is the sql injection attacks you are inviting by not using parameterized queries. There's no excuse for that.